# How do I refresh part of a page when a checkbox is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple checkbox list on my website.

What I need is: when the user clicks on one or two selections, the page reloads just showing images related of the selection the user made and hiding all the rest.

I don't want the whole page to reload, just the body which is where my divs are.

To make my point clear, here is an example: 
http://www.entel.pe/personas/catalogo-equipos/

On the vertical bar at the left, click on "Marcas" , and then if you click on one or two selections on that list, you will see only one block of the site loads and hides all the pictures in the right except the ones related to your selection.

```html
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<div class="brands_products"><!--brands_products-->
    <h2>Marcas</h2>
        <div class="brands-name">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <input id="ffc-telefonia-movil-19" name="ffc-tipo-equipo[]" class="checkbox" value="19" type="checkbox" >
                    <span class="pull-right">(50)</span>
                    <label class="margen-left-5 flotar-izq padding-top-2">Accer</label>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <input id="ffc-telefonia-movil-19" name="ffc-tipo-equipo[]" class="checkbox" value="19" type="checkbox">
                    <span class="pull-right">(10)</span>
                    <label class="margen-left-5 flotar-izq padding-top-2">Apple</label>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <input id="ffc-telefonia-movil-19" name="ffc-tipo-equipo[]" class="checkbox" value="19" type="checkbox">
                    <span class="pull-right">(8)</span>
                    <label class="margen-left-5 flotar-izq padding-top-2">HP</label>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <input id="ffc-telefonia-movil-19" name="ffc-tipo-equipo[]" class="checkbox" value="19" type="checkbox">
                    <span class="pull-right">(27)</span>
                    <label class="margen-left-5 flotar-izq padding-top-2">Lenovo</label>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <input id="ffc-telefonia-movil-19" name="ffc-tipo-equipo[]" class="checkbox" value="19" type="checkbox">
                    <span class="pull-right">(30)</span>
                    <label class="margen-left-5 flotar-izq padding-top-2">Sansung</label>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <input id="ffc-telefonia-movil-19" name="ffc-tipo-equipo[]" class="checkbox" value="50" type="checkbox">
                    <span class="pull-right">(19)</span>
                    <label class="margen-left-5 flotar-izq padding-top-2">Sony</label>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div><!--/brands_products-->
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: i think it is about ajax..you do transaction using ajax without leaving the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're looking for AJAX. The basic idea is that you watch for an event from your checkbox. (Examples assume you're using jQuery.)

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() { //when checked or unchecked... });
```

And depending on the change you call new content onto the page and replace the existing content. (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
  url: "newContent.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function( html ) {
  $( '#main_section' ).html( html );
});
```

Generally speaking, this means that you need to have the alternative content remotely available. Either on another page on your server or in a database somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax to do the request for the new images rather than loading the images on load you can dynamically pull these images and data from the DB using jquery and ajax.

You can google examples or check how to do it on here.

Comment: Thank for replying, It seems Ajax is the only way to go. sadly, I am still a newbie at javascript. I dont want to bother more but, do you have any video or site where I can see about this ? because I dont even know how to search a video for this special need. thank for you reply!

Comment: w3schools is probably the best place to start so check it out. You can also search stackoverflow for tips :)